# resolving same generic-name functions via size of argument

Tags: interface, fortran

I'd like to have a function interface that resolves which specific procedure is to be used depending on the size of an array argument. I could then, for example, have a program that handles vectors with less than or exactly N elements with one procedure and longer vectors with another one. As far as I know, Fortran only resolves using types, ranks and keywords of the arguments. Why is that? Aren't compilers intelligent enough to differentiate between arrays of different sizes or is it intrinsically impossible to write a compiler that does that?

Is there a workaround to achieve the desired functionality? I know of course that I could write a subroutine with an if-clause to sort out which procedure to use for which array size. Wouldn't that cost more CPU time though?

Comment: I have found a workaround, which is to `RESHAPE` the actual N-element vector to a rank-N array of column size 1. This can be done on the fly if the dummy argument is `INTENT(IN)`. Any suggestions better than this hack are still welcome.

Comment: Why would you need to write the if-clause a million times? Can't you just write a wrapper routine which checks the size and then calls the appropriate lower-level subroutine?

Comment: I expressed myself wrongly there. What I meant was that the if-clause will be repeatedly executed, therefore costing CPU time. I may be mistaken about this, but I think that having an interface that resolves the difference between, say, rank-1 arrays of size 1 and rank-1 arrays of larger sizes would be faster.

Comment: ... although I now see the point IanH is making below: since I want the routine to handle rank-1 arrays of all sizes (assuming a single type), I can see how this might be equivalent to an if.

Answer (score 3):

Resolution of specific procedures has been designed so that it is something which can be done at compile time.  In the general case the size of an array is a run time concept.

If you know at compile time that a certain specific procedure is more suitable for certain input, then you can call that specific procedure directly.

Otherwise use IF to test and branch on the size (If the language had this sort of magic that's all that it would be doing behind the scenes anyway).  That test and branch is likely to be substantially faster than calling reshape at runtime anyway.

Comment: Is the size of a dummy array a run-time concept even when I declare it to have a specific `DIMENSION`? If yes, why? The dimension is hard-coded. Why are Fortran compilers agnostic to it?

Comment: You'd need to have both dummy and actual argument sizes constant for it to be compile time, which is very much not the general case.  From the point of view of the language standard, writing (and programmers then understanding) the specification for disambiguation requirements and how specific procedures are resolved would be a nightmare.  Lots of effort required for IMHO *very* marginal benefit.  Compilers may well take into account constant explicit shape dimension specifications to emit emitting warnings about size mismatches, etc; but that's separate to language design.